# windows 10 not booting after install ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, dual-boot, windows-10, linux-headers

I cleaned my laptop totally and installed Windows 10 first in legacy bios. I just installed, it does not have any drivers installed. Later I made dual boot with Ubuntu 16.04. After installing Ubuntu, it successfully boot into the Ubuntu, but when i tried to boot windows 10, a blank screen appears with purple color and it is not booting. Unchecked the fast startup in windows 10, but not working.

Comment: Have you disabled Secure Boot in the BIOS ? You will probably want to take a look at "boot repair ISO".  https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home/Home/

Comment: Grub only boots working Windows. So if Windows updates turn fast start back on, or the NTFS needs chkdsk, then grub will not boot Windows 10. Generally better to install Windows 10 in UEFI mode if you have UEFI hardware, so then you can directly boot Windows from UEFI. With BIOS you have to temporarily reinstall a Windows boot loader or use your Windows repair flash drive or installers repair console.

Comment: I think your procedure was correct and should work. You are saying you have Win10 up and running, i.e. you were able to login and the system was not in *progress* of installing something? When Win10 was not fully finished installation you might need to start over again because it could be anything. Other than that make sure your BIOS did not forget the Legacy mode. Last tip try to use the Windows Install CD in Repair mode. I used them only up to Win7, but they have not changed since XP and should be very similar for Win10 (maybe google for Recovery CD).